# Dynamically loading DLL referencing other DLLs

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dll, system.reflection

I'm working in C# .Net 4.0

I have the following parts of the architecture:

1. three "general" DLLs : X.dll , Y.dll, and Z.dll
2. one "particular" DLL (A.dll) that is referencing the "general" DLLs
3. one C# application that dynamically loads the A.dll 
   (I use `System.Reflection.Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename)`)

Since the application doesn't explicitly reference those "general" DLLs, I get an exception.

So my question is whether there is any chance to create the A.dll the way that would allow loading this DLL without the need to load those "general" DLLs. It seems that I can't transfer my A.dll without remembering about all the DLLs it is referencing.

I believe there is a good logic behind the way how it is done in C# 4.0, but maybe there are some exceptions to this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to execute code from A.dll or access it's resources?

Comment: Is A being packaged up and deploy in any particular way? If so, could you include the "general" DLLs as part of that deployment and add them all to the application directory so they are "visible" to the main app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your application only loads `A.dll` therefore that's the only DLL that's copied into the output directory so when `A` attempts to access code from `X` it fails because the app doesn't know where `X` is therefore can't load it.

The easiest solution here would be to install the other "general" DLLs into the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). Or alternatively, just ship the "general" DLLs with your app because they won't be loaded unless you use `A` anyway, although, they are unnecessary bloat on your install/app size if they aren't required.

Comment: he never said he's referencing `A.dll` but loading it dynamically, which means `A.dll` is probably not in the output directory.

Comment: @Eluvatar by reference what I really meant was "load", in other words, the application knows *where* to load `A` from the problem is it doesn't know where to load the rest from.

Comment: If X, Y, Z, got to the same directory as A was loading from, would that be "enough"?

Comment: @JeffBridgman Assuming X, Y & Z are referenced from A (which they appear to be) then yes it should be, that or placing them in the GAC. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) the CLR checks the GAC first and then queries the codebase directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is same what described above

"The problem here is your application only loads A.dll therefore that's the only DLL that's copied into the output directory so when A attempts to access code from X it fails because the app doesn't know where X is therefore can't load it."

But you can put these three "general" DLLs : X.dll , Y.dll, and Z.dll into a folder say genDllFolder

```
    String genDllFolder = "yourpath/genDllFolder";
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(genDllFolder);
    System.Reflection.Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename));
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. In this, can I just call `Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);` once and after that refer all the classes within it without all those complicated reflection calls?

Comment: Yes, you can reference directly also before compilation

Comment: But do I need to use reflection in that case? If a class `class Foo` is present in dll then can I simply do `Foo fObj = new Foo();` ?

Comment: Yes if you had added that dll in visual studio Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box before compilation..
See, if ComplexNumber.dll class needed Integer.dll and String.dll then you can directly add Integer.dll and String.dll to your solution using Dialog Box and then `Assembly.LoadFrom(filenameofComplexnodll);` will produce no error.
If you don't want to add it statically from Dialog box before compilation use above method.